# Webhook Url not working on Uber Production Environment

Tags: uber-api

We have integrated Uber API in our application. And receiving updates regarding ride status in our mobile app through web services using a Webhook url. We were receiving updates regarding rides on the Webhook Url consistently till day before yesterday. But, since yesterday, the Webhook Url is not being hit consistently, as a ride is booked or is in progress or has completed. Sometimes the Webhook url is never hit or there is a considerable delay. Need help in debugging this issue.

Comment: This sounds like a bug on Uber's side. We're looking into it.

Comment: Update: This was an issue on our end and it has been fixed. Sorry for the missing webhooks. Please let us know if the problem persists.